# force center form in foreground + the middle of the screen ax 2009

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I just created a form in AX 2009, and I would like to force it to open:
 1. In the foreground
 2. In the center of the screen.
You can find attached a screenshot with the display node properties, in case I didn't set something right.
I also looked in the run method but I can't find the right syntax for this.
Thanks in advance for any help.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Your image link appears to be broken. And do you have any starting code you're working with?

Comment: When you say "In the foreground" do you mean that form should be modal?

Comment: Hi Alex, 
No, it's just a simple form "triggered" from the StartUpPost method.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the user's screen size/resolution you would either need to calculate the screen width/height to know where the center is like this:

```
#WinAPI
int screenWidth = WinAPI::getSystemMetrics(#SM_CXSCREEN);
int screenHeight = WinAPI::getSystemMetrics(#SM_CYSCREEN);
```

**ALTERNATIVELY**, and the simplest, just put this in the form's init method:

```
element.design().topMode(FormTop::Center);
element.design().leftMode(FormLeft::Center);
```

Answer (score 1):

To center form in **middle of the screen** use this functions

```
element.design().left(44, 4); //Center
element.design().top(220, 3); //Center
```

You can use this code in `init()` method of your form.

***For Example:***

```
public void init()
{
    super();

    element.design().left(44, 4); //Center
    element.design().top(220, 3); //Center
}
```

When open your form **AX** show the form in foreground.

Comment: Your code accomplishes the same thing, but is a little misleading as the `44` and `220` don't do anything. The second argument where you pass a `4` and a `3` are actually the form modes for the enums that equate to `FormLeft::Center` and `FormTop::Center` respectively.

Comment: Exactly Alex, your code and this code works fine. Your code is more clear and is better understood :)